# import excel to mysql use python and convert datestamp

Tags: python, mysql

I need data in excel - date(20180301) and time(121220) like this int type.
I want import excel to mysql use python convert datestamp (%t-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) for one coulm.

```
import xlrd
import pymysql
import time
import datetime
#open the workbook and define rhe worksheet
book  = xlrd.open_workbook("d:/waiting2.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
ts = time.time()
timestamp = datetime.datetime.formtimestamp(ts).strftime('%t-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

#establish a mysql connection
database = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user='root', password='1234',db='test')

#get the cursor, which is used to traverse the database, line by line
cursor = database.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT into test(date+time) values($s)""", (timestamp))
    database.commit()
except:
    database.rollback()

database.close()
```

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'formtimestamp'

Comment: Why do you need to go through Python?  What would be wrong with trying to load the data directly from Excel into MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as what the exception is, `'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'formtimestamp'`, because it should be `fromtimestamp` (see the difference ?).
and what's more, you can use 'pandas' module to deal with data works.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('d:/waiting2.xlsx')
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connect = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/test')
# assume that you are using mysql as your DBM and 3306 as the port.
df.to_sql('test', connect, index=False, if_exists='append')
# and before this you should convert datatime string yourself.
```

Comment: I try connect= create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:PW@localhost:3306/test') but error in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'". so I install mysqldb but Could not find a version...how can I fixed?

Comment: which version of python are you using? you can try pymysql instead if you are using python3.

Comment: Use python 3.6 version and I install pymysql.

Comment: you need to change the connection url to pymysql instead, sqlalchemy won't use pymysql automatically, that means `connect= create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:PW@localhost:3306/test')` (remember to change the PW and root to your own password and user name.)